# Shiny in RStudio server docker container returns WebSocket error in Firefox

Tags: r, docker, firefox, shiny, rstudio

I'm having trouble loading my ShinyApps in localhost in rocker/rstudio docker container.
Now, it happens only in a specific situation: when I'm locally running the app inside this container in Firefox.

Resume:

1. Local RStudio local app in Chrome/Firefox; - OK
2. Docker RStudio local app in Chrome; - OK
3. Docker RStudio ShinyServer app in Chrome/Firefox; - OK
4. Docker RStudio local app in Firefox; - DEFINITELY NOT OK

In the JavaScript console in Firefox, it returns

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8787/p/8100/websocket/.
```

This started happening after I installed R package `shinytest` and `PhantomJS` (required for the package). It didn't work. I thought that was the cause, so I completely removed my container and uninstalled PhantomJS and Firefox. Then I reran the container from scrap and reinstalled Firefox. Still, no success. So maybe it's a coincidence?

I've tried looking for an answer everywhere and I've only found solutions regarding a similar problem using nginx, but my container doesn't even use nginx. Plus, everything works fine on Chrome.

I'm completely lost here. I'd appreciate any help.